# How do you access Multidimensional-Array properties from dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, drop-down-menu

I am working on an assignment for my JS class and I am trying to figure out how to access a specific property from an array based on user selection from a drop down menu. (I tend to try things that are ahead of what we are studying and get stuck in these binds)

First off I don't know what to actually call this data. Dataframe? Subset? Map? Array? Multi property object list? (after creating tags for this post I am wondering if this is a multidimensional-array)

I apologize if it is not described well.

So far I have been able to access the each property directly but have not figured out how to do that through the user select menu. I added ids to the value attribute for the options but don't know how to use that to access the rest of the properties after selection.

Here is my script

```
const flavors = [
    {
        "flavor":"Tangy Taro Eggy",
        "description":"",
        "img_src":"images/tangy-taro-eggy.jpg",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "flavor":"Beetle Bark Raspberry",
        "description":"",
        "img_src":"images/beetle-bark-raspberry.jpg",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "flavor":"Cali CBD-licious Creme",
        "description":"",
        "img_src":"images/cali-cbd-licious-creme.jpg",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "flavor":"Durian Delight",
        "description":"",
        "img_src":"images/durian-delight.jpg",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "flavor":"Vanilla",
        "description":"",
        "img_src":"vanilla.jpg",
        "id": 5
    }
];     
var select = document.getElementById("flavor_list"); //this is the id for <select> element in my HTML

flavors.forEach(function populate_list(item){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    var img_src =flavors.img_src; //This one doesn't do anything becuase the value isn't read (which I don't know what that means) 
    //I tried defining this variable outside of the function as well but the alert still doesnt work
    option.value = item.id; // I created unique values for each option but don't know how to use them to get more info
    option.innerHTML = item.flavor;
    select.appendChild(option)
})
select.onchange = function fetch_info() {
   alert(this.img_src) // this is just a test to see if I got the info. 
//Once I figure this out I will be able to complete there rest of the assignment
}
```

It would be best to stick with just JS and not use Jquery or anything like that because we haven't learned any of that yet.

I appreciate any help

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to get it's value as an id and loop through the array and find the exact flavor...

Example:

```
select.onchange = function (e) {
     const id = e.target.value;
    
   // find the set which has this id, as you have passed the option value your id
   const flavor = flavors.filter(({ id: flavorId }) => +id === flavorId)[0];
   
   console.log(flavor) // this is just a test to see if I got the info. 
//Once I figure this out I will be able to complete there rest of the assignment
}
```

EDIT: Be sure that, you flavor id is unique.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Console is returning  [{…}]. Any other ideas?

Comment: Am i right, when select changes you want get an object with the data ? If so, answer is updated, could you check it please ?

Comment: Yes I would like to get data from the array based on the value from the selection. So if it selection returns a 1 for the id I can pull the name, image and description and display it below. And yes I will check again, thank you for you help

Comment: Now it is coming back undefined. is flavorID supposed to be from the array or is that unique to the function you wrote?

Comment: flavorId is comming from array which i have distructed. Could you check this link https://jsfiddle.net/tzokwp1s/6/

Comment: It is working! I had changed something above that broke it, oops. Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229367/discussion-between-kevin-mcgreal-and-fayzzzm).